# Can be this type definition unified?

Tags: typescript

I created:

```js
type NumberFields<T, K extends keyof T> = T[K] extends number ? K : never;
type AnsFields<T> = SomeOtherList & NumberFields<T, keyof T>;
```

SomeOtherList is pre-defined field names, like `'foo' | 'bar'`.

The type definition works correctly, but I want only `AnsFields<T>`. Can I inline the definition of `NumberFields` to `AnsFields`? I couldn't find the way to do.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Yes you can inline `NumberFields`, but I find this less readable:

```
type AnsFields<T> = SomeOtherList &
    { [K in keyof T]: T[K] extends number ? K : never }[keyof T];
```

Basically we're inlining lookup by keys

Comment: How interesting! Thanks!